# Proto DataStore Recompose On Updates

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, proto-datastore

I have managed to set up Proto DataStore in my Jetpack Compose project.
My Proto DataStore is defined by .proto file that has a list of objects.

I have successfully been able to observe values from the Proto DataStore:

```
 var myProtoObject: MyProtoObjectType?
 viewModel.myFlow.observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) { obj ->
                myProtoObject = obj
            }
```

Part of my UI has a lazyColumn that renders the objects from the Proto DataStore.
Usually, when working with a lazyColumn, you can define a mutable state variable for the lists' items (or collectAsState/observeAsState).

The problem is, that while the flow works properly and gives updates, it does not cause recomposition.

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxSize()
           .padding(paddingValues)) {
               item {
                      Row(
                          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                          horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                        ) {
                           //Content here
                        }
                   }
                   myProtoObject?.itemsList?.let {
                       items(it) { item ->
                                // Content here
                        }
                      }
            }
```

How would one trigger recomposition when updates are received from the flow?

**EDIT**

The .proto file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.example.example2";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message ListItem{
  string itemId = 1;
  string itemDescription = 2;
}

message ListItems{
  repeated ListItem items = 1;
}
```

I also tried doing the following, but it did not work:

```
var obj: List<ListItem> = remember {
   mutableListOf()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose requires a state for recomposition. Here, you are using `var myProtoObject: MyProtoObjectType?` which is not a state, just normal variable. Therefore, compose does not recognize the need to recompose when this object changes.

You can achieve your goal with codes at below. Additionally, keep in mind that the flow is reset in situations such as screen rotations. You might also want to consider using `StateFlow` instead. You can use it in the same way as `collectAsState`.

First way:

```
val myProtoObject by viewModel.myFlow.collectAsState(initial = null)
```

Second way:

```
var itemsList:  List<YourItem> by  remember { mutableStateOf(listOf()) }

viewModel.myFlow.observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) { obj ->
    itemsList = obj.itemsList
}

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .padding(paddingValues)) {
    item {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            //Content here
        }
    }

    items(itemsList) {
        // Content here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but prior to posting this question, I tried the second approach and got an error (which I edited the question with).

Comment: Since it was stated that it could be null, such an error should not have occurred. You can provide `mutableStateOf` with an empty `MyProtoObjectType`as an initial value. This solution resolves the issue.

Comment: Doing that is impossible since when trying to do so, the error I get is cannot access init it is private in MyProtoObjectType. Since this class is generated, you cannot make changes to it.

Comment: Then it makes more sense to use the direct list as state. Edited check please

Comment: Faruk Karaca - But my proto data type is not a list. It contains an object that is a list. You can see it in the code I shared above -> ```myProtoObject?.itemsList```

Comment: I know. You should give that list directly to `LazyColum`. I edited it to be clearer.

Comment: You are using `= remember`. I use `by remember`. If you are going to use `= remember`, you must specify the type as `MutableState<List<YourItem>>` and get it with `.value` when using it. Since I use it with `by remember`, there is no need for this. I'm sorry, but you really didn't follow the answer I sent properly. I applied the same thing to an application in which I already use `Proto dataStore`, and it works easily with both methods. So I don't know other solution :D

Comment: Your are correct. My apologies.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked